# ArcGIS - Is it possible to bypass an inaccurate WMS bounding box provided by server metadata?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms

In ArcGIS Desktop, is there a way to bypass / ignore an inaccurate WMS bounding box provided by server metadata?

Indeed, for a specific WMS layer I am using, the bounding box provided by server metadata does not match the underlying data's extent (some data exist out of the "official" bounding box delivered by metadata request). Thus, I would like to prevent ArcGIS from using the inaccurate metadata so that I can see all of the data.

Comment: Well, if you're nominally skilled in Java, you could write a HTTP proxy which would pass through most requests and responses, but rewrite the metadata response.